# React Native Modal prevent unmount

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a WebView that I show inside the React Native Modal. I would like to hide the modal for sometime and on callback I want to show the Modal again to the user for some input.

The problem is if I change state and hide the React Native modal then it unmounts the child component that has WebView and if I show it back, the WebView reloads.

I want to only hide the modal, not to kill it so that I can show it from where user left. I have tried React Navigation but that also doesn't solve the purpose.

Any direction would be helpful.

Comment: I think you have used react native native modal. May be https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox will help you to solve this issue.

Comment: @KishanBharda, I have already tried that but same result. Also if I'm not wrong, react-native-modalbox underneath uses the same React Native Modal.

Answer (score -1):

Well i think you can set the Modal Container Size to width=0, height= 0, this way the modal wont be unmount but hidden from the user eye.